# On Phabricator get the comment from a feed story

Tags: phabricator

I'm using Phabricator's `feed.http-hooks` feature to post messages in a dev chat room whenever relevant events happen in the news feed. This works great for showing that "Alice created diff D12345" or "Bob updated diff D54321."

When someone comments on a diff, I want to extract the comment text from the story. Whenever there's a comment, Phabricator sends HTTP POSTs to my `feed.http-hooks` server containing parameters like the following:

```
storyID=42
storyType=PhabricatorApplicationTransactionFeedStory
storyData[objectPHID]=PHID-DREV-blahblah1
storyData[transactionPHIDs][0]=PHID-DREV-blahblah2
storyAuthorPHID=PHID-USER-blahblah3
storyText=tom added a comment to D12345: Some random diff.
epoch=1412243745
```

My question is, how can I get the actual text of the comment? I've tried using Conduit's `phid.query` method to look up some of these PHIDs, but that hasn't gotten me anywhere. I know this is possible because the comment shows up in the actual "Recent Activity" feed on the Phabricator site. Halp.